# trouble converting from void pointer to char pointer

Tags: c, cryptography, gmp

I'm using the paillier library for cryptography.

There is a function namely `paillier_ciphertext_to_bytes` which converts to bytes. Upon checking the paillier.h, it has the return type void*.

I would like to take the string this generates which I believe is hex, and convert it to a decimal number using strtol.

However, when I cast the output of `paillier_ciphertext_to_bytes` to a char*, it doesn't work as expected.

This is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<gmp.h>
//#include<paillier.h>
#include"paillier.h"
#include <string.h>
#include<malloc.h>

int main()
{
 int n=4; //degree of polynomial
 int i=0;
 char* str;

 paillier_pubkey_t *pub_key=(paillier_pubkey_t *)malloc(sizeof(paillier_pubkey_t));
 paillier_prvkey_t *prv_key=(paillier_prvkey_t *)malloc(sizeof(paillier_prvkey_t));
 paillier_keygen(4,&pub_key,&prv_key,paillier_get_rand_devrandom);

 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {  
  unsigned int p=rand()%20;
  paillier_plaintext_t *ptext = paillier_plaintext_from_ui(p);
  
  
  paillier_ciphertext_t *ctext;
  ctext = paillier_enc(0, pub_key, ptext, paillier_get_rand_devrandom);
  
  str = (char*)paillier_ciphertext_to_bytes(n,ctext);
  printf("str==[%s]\n",str);
  printf("number_str==[%d]\n",(int)strtol(str,NULL,16));
 }

 return 0;
}
```

This is the output I get

```
str==[]
number_str==[0]
str==[]
number_str==[0]
str==[]
number_str==[0]
str==[]
number_str==[0]
```

[This](https://github.com/tradams/alice-bob-sip/blob/master/libs/libpaillier-0.8/paillier.h) is the paillier.h library code, where I looked up the signature of `paillier_ciphertext_to_bytes`

**Side note,**

I only want to convert the encryption to a number. Actually there is no reason for me to believe that `paillier_ciphertext_to_bytes` can be cast to a char*. So, I've also tried converting it to an int* and then print out it's value as follows

```
int* myintp;
myintp = (int*)paillier_ciphertext_to_bytes(n,ctext);
printf("number==[%d]\n",*myintp);
```

This always give me an integer number, but I'm not sure if this is correct(the decimal representation of the encrypted string)

EDIT :
As per Felix's comment, I've tried this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<gmp.h>
//#include<paillier.h>
#include"paillier.h"
#include <string.h>
#include<malloc.h>

int main()
{
 int n=4; //degree of polynomial
 int i=0;
 void* myvoid;
 FILE* fp;

 fp = fopen("file.txt","a");

 paillier_pubkey_t *pub_key=(paillier_pubkey_t *)malloc(sizeof(paillier_pubkey_t));
 paillier_prvkey_t *prv_key=(paillier_prvkey_t *)malloc(sizeof(paillier_prvkey_t));
 paillier_keygen(4,&pub_key,&prv_key,paillier_get_rand_devrandom);

 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {  
  unsigned int p=rand()%20;
  paillier_plaintext_t *ptext = paillier_plaintext_from_ui(p);
  
  
  paillier_ciphertext_t *ctext;
  ctext = paillier_enc(0, pub_key, ptext, paillier_get_rand_devrandom);
  
  myvoid=paillier_ciphertext_to_bytes(PAILLIER_BITS_TO_BYTES(pub_key->bits)*2, ctext);
  fwrite(myvoid, 1, PAILLIER_BITS_TO_BYTES(pub_key->bits)*2, fp); 
  printf("as int : %d\n",*(int*)myvoid);
  printf("as str : %d\n",(int)strtol((char*)myvoid,NULL,16));
 }

 fclose(fp);
  
 return 0;
}
```

But I get unprintable characters in my output file when I try to print myvoid, and when I cast to integer and string, I get this output

```
as int : 31136768
as str : 0
as int : 493106432
as str : 0
as int : 493111552
as str : 0
as int : 493092864
as str : 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the library in question, it's pretty clear from the name of the function what it does: It gives you the actual encrypted bytes contained in some library-specific container type. Of course you can just take it as `char *` (there's no need to cast and you shouldn't, but that's another question).

Typically encrypted data contains *any* possible byte value, which includes `0` as well as non-printable characters and so on. So, having a `char *` pointer to it doesn't make it a *C string*. What you would do now is *encode* it in some ascii encoding, often `base64` is used. This would give you a string representation suitable for writing to a file or sending in an email.

About the part of interpreting it as an `int`: This is a very bad idea. As encrypted data can contain any possible byte values, it really should only be treated as this: bytes. With `int` you could have for example two different representations of `0`, so you'd lose information. And that's just *one* example of what could go wrong.

`char *` or `void *` is the correct type for a sequence of arbitrary bytes. Of course, to do anything useful with it, you need to know *how many bytes there are* in the encrypted form. Look in your library's documentation for how to know.

Comment: please see edit above. I have looked at the size documentation, but still get unprintable characters when I cast (void*) to char* and print them. I don't know if doing (int*) is giving me the correct answer.

Comment: @PepperBoy Then please read my answer again: Something encrypted is typically a sequence of **arbitrary** bytes, of course containing unprintable characters. Interpreting them as `int` (note the size of an `int` depends on your platform) is almost certainly wrong. If you want something you can print, use e.g. *base64* to encode your bytes in text.